# Single Word for Anti-Racism?

Tags: racism

Is there a single word in the English language that defines an individual that hates racists?

I've always used "anti-racist" or "anti-racism" or "anti-hate" but there must be a single word in the English language that descibes the situation I'm referring to better, right?  ...Without resorting to hyphenation?

Comment: Do you want a term for a racist-hater, or simply someone who is race-agnostic?

Comment: Lol. Racist-hater is almost an oxymoron, isn't it?  But yes. Something very similar to it.

Comment: @user201476 I wouldn't call it an [oxymoron](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oxymoron); that implies that racist and hater are contrasting ideas. Perhaps you're looking for *tautology*.

Comment: I'd say Tolerant, but i'm not really sure.

Comment: You can try saying you're "aracist"? ;D

Comment: Lol, galois. :-D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not aware of a direct antonym of *racist* or *racism*. A person that opposes **any** form of discrimination is called ***egalitarian***.

> **egalitarian**
>
> adjective
>   of, relating to, or believing in the principle that all people are equal and deserve equal rights and
>   opportunities : *a fairer, more egalitarian society.*
>
> noun
>    a person
>   who advocates or supports such a principle.

New Oxford American Dictionary

Comment: Michael, thanks very much. I wouldn't have found this on my own and I think it describes exactly what I want to get across to people.  Sounds way better than anything with a hyphen as well.

Comment: @user201476 Bear in mind that people that describe theirselves as "egalitarian" wouldn't _hate_ racists. Surely they won't agree with racist views, but hating some group (racists) over some other group (non-racists) is, by definition, out of the equation.

Comment: @walen: Racism isn't about discriminating against a group of people. It's about discriminating against a group of people when the trait discrimination is based on is irrelevant to the discrimination. Being egalitarian doesn't somehow define away the need for discrimination against people whose behavior is detrimental to said egalitarian's way of life. A sufficiently disruptive racist could certainly be hated without any conflict of definition.

Comment: @user201476 Hating racists is neither required nor precluded by being egalitarian.

Comment: @MichaelS I guess the word "hate" carries a heavier emotional load to me. I see "hate" as an active emotion (even when that hate is repressed because of laws etc.), as opposed to e.g. "dislike" or "antipathy" which to me are more of passive emotions. "Hate" is associated with actions like "hate crime". Making "hateful remarks" about someone is not the same as making "unpleasant remarks". Racist people _hate_ other people; an egalitarian myself, I don't like racists, but I don't actively _hate_ them: I just think that they are wrong and laws should be in place to keep them from hurting society.

Comment: @walen An egalitarian might well hate (in the strongest sense) groups such as ISIS. Such hatred is not associated with hate (or any other type of) crimes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry, I don't agree. You can't say "ISIS people are equal and deserve equal rights and opportunities" and "I hate ISIS people" at the same time. Either you have a very lax view of what egalitarianism is, or (as I said before) your concept of hate is milder than mine. Let's agree that we disagree :-)

Comment: @walen At this very moment a coalition of governments subscribing to the egalitarian creed is trying to **kill** these people. Is that a concept milder than your hate? Being egalitarian does not mean being a saint.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please don't mix politics into this, this is not the place to debate whether the US (racial and gender issues, Guantanamo), Russia (gay imprisonment, political assassinations), or France (racial issues, hijab ban) actually follow the egalitarian principles or just say so. I will stop commenting now, since I think you're taking my comments as an attack to your answer (they aren't, it's a good answer) and it's already clear that you base your concept of "egalitarian" in the acts of people that say they are egalitarians, instead of the definition of the word itself. Cheers.

Comment: @walen "*you base your concept of "egalitarian" in the acts of people that say they are egalitarians, instead of the definition of the word itself*" No. All I am saying is that the definition of *egalitarian* is concerned with *discrimination*, not with *hate* - these are two entirely different concepts.

Comment: An egalitarian might even take stance against some measures (eg these under the affirmative action label) installed to combat racism.

Answer (score 3):

"**A social activist**" might fit, except for the fact that although they may spend (or may have spent) their whole lives fighting racism, they don't necessarily hate racists.

> - Activism, in a general sense, can be described as intentional action to bring about social, political, economic, or environmental change. This action is in support of, or opposition to, one side of an often controversial argument:
>     *I am a "Social Activist" and I would like to spread knowledge, and support charities and our brothers and sisters in arms.*  [from UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Social%20Activist)

Some famous social activists

- Martin Luther King Jr
- Malcolm X
- Buffy Sainte-Marie
- Mother Jones
- Jesse Jackson
- Muhammad Ali
- Joan Baez

Answer (score 1):

humanist

Wikipedia:  "Humanism is a philosophical and ethical stance that emphasizes the value and agency of human beings, individually and collectively, and generally prefers critical thinking and evidence (rationalism, empiricism) over acceptance of dogma or superstition."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism

By valuing all people, a humanist is anti-racism, but not necessarily against the racist.

Answer (score -3):

the word is ***educated***.  One caveat: an educated person will hate racism, but not the racist.

I say educated is the word, because an educated person knows that all humans now living are descended from a small population in Africa.  And all humans now living outside Africa are descended from a small band that left Africa about 50,000 years ago.  See [National Geographic News](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2008/02/080221-human-genetics.html) article *Massive Genetic Study Supports Out of Africa Theory*.  The evidence is incontrovertible.

There were earlier out of Africa migrations -- the ancestors of the Neandertals left Africa perhaps 500,000 years ago, and the ancestors of the homo erectus specimens found in Asia even earlier.  But every racist (and everyone else) alive today is an African.  No kind of racism makes sense, because we are all cousins.

Obligatory English citation:  [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59581?redirectedFrom=educated#eid), **educated**

> 2.....(of an opinion, etc.) based on an understanding of relevant facts or issues; informed

Comment: +1 for "an educated person will hate racism, but not the racist."

Comment: Is there a shortage of educated racists?

Comment: Me, I'm educated and I hate the racist along with the racism.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - There is a subtle difference between *educated* and *taught*.

Comment: @HotLicks That is a circular argument.

Comment: There are plenty of educated racists. This isn't the correct answer at all.

Comment: I agree that education is one of the keys to transcending prejudices and cultural ignorance.  But racism is not something you're born with; it too is "learned."

Comment: To learn something isn't the same as being educated. In that train of thought, you learn everything, from breathing to calculating.